# controls (buttons, labels..) in interface builder

Tags: interface-builder

when i create a new app with interface builder, the buttons toolbar is not display, it suppose to be displayed in the right, please what to do, thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Cmd-Shift-L and the Library will show up. You can also use the menus at the top to make it show up.